# Tag synonym: "Prepared-Statements" -> "Prepared-Statement"

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

While asking a [question tonight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319570/how-do-i-properly-get-a-sql-datetime-back-into-my-java-application), I discovered that SO has both a Prepared-Statement tag and a Prepared-Statement***s*** tag.

Given that there are 300+ of the latter, and less than 20 of the former, I'd like to suggest that Prepared-Statements (and it's own tag synonym, "PreparedStatements") be synonym-'d with the non-plural version.

I lack both the rep and tag answer score to propose the synonym or retag the few questions in question, and given the relative obscurity of the tag, I doubt it will get handled swiftly on its own. On the other hand, given the relative obscurity, maybe it's a non-issue?